# sum data from the given dataset and show the output as follows in mysql query

Tags: mysql

**Data Set**

| VendorName | Amount | Name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Green Delta Insurance Company Ltd. | 100 | Saroar | 20 |
| Green Delta Insurance Company Ltd. | 200 | Ahmed | 30 |
| Sena Kalyan Insurance Company Ltd. | 300 | Saroar | 20 |
| Sena Kalyan Insurance Company Ltd. | 400 | Ahmed | 30 |

**Expected Output**

| VendorName | Amount | Name With Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Green Delta Insurance Company Ltd. | 300 | Saroar - 20, Ahmed - 30 |
| Sena Kalyan Insurance Company Ltd. | 700 | Saroar - 20, Ahmed - 30 |

Comment: Let me know if the proposed answer works for you

Answer (score 1):

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  `VendorName` VARCHAR(34),
  `Amount` INTEGER,
  `Name` VARCHAR(6),
  `Age` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO my_table
  (`VendorName`, `Amount`, `Name`, `Age`)
VALUES
  ('Green Delta Insurance Company Ltd.', '100', 'Saroar', '20'),
  ('Green Delta Insurance Company Ltd.', '200', 'Ahmed', '30'),
  ('Sena Kalyan Insurance Company Ltd.', '300', 'Saroar', '20'),
  ('Sena Kalyan Insurance Company Ltd.', '400', 'Ahmed', '30');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
    VendorName,
    SUM(AMOUNT) Amount,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Name,' - ',Age)) as 'Name With Age'
FROM
    my_table
GROUP BY VendorName;
```

| VendorName | Amount | Name With Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Green Delta Insurance Company Ltd. | 300 | Saroar - 20,Ahmed - 30 |
| Sena Kalyan Insurance Company Ltd. | 700 | Saroar - 20,Ahmed - 30 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gX8zXLkDYMxHSobVjfm35p/1)

### Update 1

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  `VendorName` VARCHAR(34),
  `Amount` INTEGER,
  `Name` VARCHAR(6),
  `Age` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO my_table
  (`VendorName`, `Amount`, `Name`, `Age`)
VALUES
  ('Green Delta Insurance Company Ltd.', '100', 'Saroar', '20'),
  ('Green Delta Insurance Company Ltd.', '200', 'Ahmed', '30'),
  ('Sena Kalyan Insurance Company Ltd.', '300', 'Saroar', '20'),
  ('Sena Kalyan Insurance Company Ltd.', '400', 'Ahmed', '30');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
    VendorName,
    SUM(AMOUNT) Amount,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Name,' - ',Amount)) as 'Name With Amount'
FROM
    my_table
GROUP BY VendorName;
```

| VendorName | Amount | Name With Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Green Delta Insurance Company Ltd. | 300 | Saroar - 100,Ahmed - 200 |
| Sena Kalyan Insurance Company Ltd. | 700 | Saroar - 300,Ahmed - 400 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gX8zXLkDYMxHSobVjfm35p/2)